# Name of distribution

Tags: probability-distributions

I am searching for the name of the following distribution on the set of positive integers (including zero).

Let $C\in \mathbb{Z}_+$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$ are fixed.

Vector $p = (p_1,\ldots,p_n)$ is such that

1) $p_i\in \mathbb{Z}_+$.
2) $\sum_{i=1}^{n}p_i = C$.

The distribition of vectors $p$ is such that every vector is equal probable.

Anyone knows the name and where to read about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the uniform distribution on any nonempty finite set whatsoever. In this case, you could call it the uniform distribution on [the set of nonnegative integer solutions to an equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/919676/the-number-of-integer-solutions-of-equations).